# texmaker "could not start the command"

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation, latex

I messed up a bit with TekLive and TexMaker in my Ubuntu 14.04. I unistalled and re-installed both a couple of times.

Now, if I go to terminal and do

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex
```

My `test.tex` file is compiled as it should be. The problem is when I try to do this from TexMaker. I get the error message

```
Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I don't get it. I added `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/i386-linux` to PATH -- of course I did, otherwise `pdflatex` wouldn't run from the terminal as it did. I don't know what else to do. I [found this question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357688/texmaker-dont-compile-latex-document-on-ubuntu) but all the answers mentioned installing (again) TexLive. I mean, my latex seems to be working, so I don't see any point in redoing that. I uninstalled and installed again TexMaker 4.3 by downloading the appropriate version from [here](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) and then doing

```
sudo gdebi texmakerQT5_ubuntu_14.04_4.3_i386
```

and got no error messages when installing.

What's going on?

Comment: According to this [Compiling with texmaker fails, compiling on commandline works](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122149/compiling-with-texmaker-fails-compiling-on-commandline-works) you may need to export the texlive path from your `.profile` rather than your `.bashrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace pdflatex under Options -> Configure Texmaker -> Commands with

```
 "/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex"
```

Comment: could you explain why? I don't understand why this is needed since `pdflatex` is in my PATH. do I have to this for the other programs as well -- i.e., bibtex and so forth?

Comment: My suspicion is that TexMaker looks for these files on standard locations rather than using the PATH variable. Unfortunately, I had to do the same for the other commands too.